# Сохранятся ли файлы при возврате в исходное состояние в win 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Удалятся ли файлы при возврате в исходное состояние и выборе "сохранить личные файлы".
Конкретно волнует сейвы игры в папке : мои документы/имя игры/имя сейва и сама игра.
Что именно удалится?

Comment: А инструкцию от производителя читать пробовали? Там описано несколько сценариев, как хотите так и делайте.
 [восстановление](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options)

Comment: Если так сильно дорожите файлами, то почему бы не перестраховаться и не сохранить их на флешке или в облаке?